# On DB2 for i, Search for Column, return table names in list form

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange, squirrel-sql

I'm still a bit of a noob, so pardon if this question is a bit obvious.  I did search for an answer but either couldn't understand how the answers I found applied, or simply couldn't find an answer.

I have a massive database housed on a DB2 for i server which I'm accessing using SQL through SQLExplorer (based on Squirrel SQL).  The tables are very poorly documented and the first order of business is figuring out how to find my way around.

I want to write a simple query that does this:

**1)** Allows me to search the entire database looking for tables that include a column called "Remarks" (which contains field descriptions).

**2)** I then want it to search that column for a keyword.

**3)** I want a table returned that includes the *names* of the tables that include that keyword (just the name, I can look up the table alphabetically later and look inside if I need to.)

I need this search to be super lightweight, and I'm hoping the concept I describe will achieve that.  Anything that eats up a lot of resources will likely anger the sys admin for the server.

Just to show I have tried (and that I am a complete noob), here's what I've got so far.

```
SELECT *
FROM <dbname>
WHERE Remarks LIKE '<keyword>'
```

Feel free to mock, I told you I'm an idiot :-).

Any help?  Perhaps at least a push in the right direction?

PS - I can't seem to find a search function in SQLExplorer, if someone knows if I can perhaps use a simple search or filter to accomplish this same goal...that would be great.

Comment: For what it's worth, the hardware is now IBM Power System.  They haven't shipped an AS/400 since 2000.  The OS is currently called "IBM i".  The database is "DB2 for i".

Comment: Thanks for the correction @Warren.  I'll keep it in mind going forward :-).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can query the system catalog to identify the tables:

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME 
FROM QSYS2.SYSCOLUMNS WHERE UPPER(DBILFL) = 'REMARKS'
```

And then query each table individually:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME WHERE Remarks LIKE '%<keyword>%'
```

See the [LIKE predicate](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzch2like.htm) for details of the pattern expression.

Comment: Again, pardon me for being so ignorant, but I can't seem to see QSYS, QADBIFLD or DBILFL anywhere in my explorer?  I'm a little hesitant to just throw this at the server without knowing where it is (or what it is, again, sorry for being so new and thanks for your help.)

Comment: QSYS is the system library (database), QADBIFLD is the file (table), and DBILFL is the field (column) containing the column names.

Comment: Okay, and I would assume every DB2 system would have one of these.  I'll give it a shot, but, I still wonder why those tables don't appear in my explorer...  Maybe it doesn't think they are important?

Comment: Every relatively current DB2/400 system should have that table.  It probably doesn't appear in your explorer because it's only showing you the contents of the default database (or the one specified on the connection).  You qualify table names with a specific library using the '.' separator.

Comment: Ah, found out when I ran the query:  I'm not authorized to see those tables.  Common problem around here (and a tedious one when I consider all the things I do have access to...)  Is there perhaps another approach (ridiculous as that sounds, even to me.)  In the mean time I'll accept the answer you gave because it should clearly work, I just don't have privileges.

Comment: By default *PUBLIC has READ authority to that table and it's pretty unusual for a system administrator to muck with authorities within QSYS as that is an IBM maintained library.

Comment: Here's the error message: [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0551 - Not authorized to object QADBIFLD in QSYS type *File.

Comment: I am open to any and all suggestions.  Including recommended readings on the subject (and perhaps a link to those docs you gave me, but for i5 instead of i7.)

Comment: Try the standard catalog names instead of the internal IBM i names.  SYSTABLES, SYSCOLUMNS and so forth.  It's in the documentation.

Comment: @Buck. Thanks, but I think the best answer is going to be to simply talk to IS.  They will likely be willing to help, and I'd rather be doing this with their knowledge than without.

Answer (score 5):

Normally i use something like this

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
       ,COLUMN_NAME,SYSTEM_COLUMN_NAME,COLUMN_HEADING          
       ,DATA_TYPE, "LENGTH",NUMERIC_SCALE
FROM QSYS2.SYSCOLUMNS
WHERE UPPER(COLUMN_NAME) LIKE '%REMARK%'
```

@JamesA, i'm at V6R1, by default, normal user are not authorized to object QADBIFLD in QSYS

Comment: Are you saying your code will not work for a normal user? I'm thinking were at V5, so...will it be the same? Or should this work for me? (Still going to talk to IS, just curious...)

Comment: @lamlam I just double checked on a V5R4 and V7R1 and the permissions are the same, *PUBLIC READ authority.  However an unprivileged user still did not have access on either version.  I wasn't aware of the QSYS2.SYSCOLUMNS view over the table but that does work.  I'll update my answer to reference that view.

Comment: @Jay Carr. This code should work for normal user. It should also works at V5 since i have been using this method since many years ago.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, many if not most IBM i shops (especially those that use RPG) stick to 10 (or less) character schema names & table names, and have a 10 (or less) character names for 'system' column names, even if longer column names are also provided.  Column text generally describes each field.

```
SELECT SYSTEM_TABLE_SCHEMA, SYSTEM_TABLE_NAME
      ,SYSTEM_COLUMN_NAME,         
      ,DATA_TYPE, "LENGTH",NUMERIC_SCALE
      ,CHAR(COLUMN_TEXT) 
FROM QSYS2.SYSCOLUMNS
WHERE UPPER(COLUMN_NAME) LIKE '%REMARK%'
```