# Finding specific data on a DB2 for i database

Tags: db2, db2-400

I'm trying to find where specific data is being saved in a database, from an as/400. I am using using IBM data studio and the DB2 to i with the as/400 driver.

So far I've been poking through all the tables and columns looking for a specific string using simple select statements, but as there are hundreds of tables/views/columns I'm at a loss.

I've looked through this thread [On DB2 for i, Search for Column, return table names in list form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750369/on-db2-for-i-search-for-column-return-table-names-in-list-form)

But I don't know the column name the data is supposed to be in, there is no documentation for this database.

Is there another way that I can search through every table/view/column for a specific string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tool called [SQL Workbench/J](http://www.sql-workbench.net)
which has a "Search table data" functionality.
Check it out but be warned - seaching for a string in a whole database / system will be expensive.

Comment: Do you mean expensive as in cost? or the load on the server?

Comment: Thank you, i'll give it a try.